# Can't add Loggly Addon on Heroku

Tags: heroku, loggly

I'm trying to install the Loggly add-on, but it's failing with a strange error:

```
heroku addons:add loggly:mole
Adding loggly:mole on payments-pixieengine-com... failed
 !    Failed to update iptables on proxy.
```

How do I install the Loggly add-on on Heroku?

Comment: Hey Daniel did you ever find a solution to this? I'm trying to install an App to Heroku that says first install Loggly ( mole ), I can't seem to find Loggly on heroku I'm guessing it has been removed, if so perhaps you have a workaround / manual install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd contact Heroku support - that's not anything you're doing wrong there.

Comment: I contacted them soon after and received no response.